# Hasse diagram for minimal element

Tags: order-theory

Let $A = \{a,b,c\}$. Use Hasse diagrams to describe all partial orderings on $A$ for which $a$ is a minimal element (there should be 10 partial orderings I guess). I know how to draw Hasse diagrams for simple posets, but this problem became relatively harder for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are ten, indeed.
I will not draw the posets, but I'll describe them to you in a way that must be easy to follow.

(1) There is one anti-chain.

(4) There are four poset consisting of a two-element chain and another element which is not connected to neither of those: in two of them, $a$ is both minimal and maximal (one with $b$ over $c$, and the other with $c$ over $b$); in the other two, one of them has $b$ over $a$, and the other has $c$ over $a$.

(2) There are two wedge-shaped posets ($\wedge$): one with $b$ on top ($a$ and $c$ on bottom) and another with $c$ on top.

(1) There's a v-shaped one, with $a$ in the bottom.

(2) There are two chains: one with $b$ on the top, and the other with $c$ on the top.

$1+4+2+1+2=10$.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for such an awesome explanation!

Comment: I just wanted to elaborate on one issue: Why there is exactly one anti-chain? I mean can't we have .a .b .c and .a .c .b on the bottom?

Comment: And also, why there are 2 wedge-shaped posets? Can't .a be located on the right side and b & c will be interchanged on the left?

Comment: @AnarRzayev Regarging your first comment, all anti-chains of the same size are isomorphic; having an element on the right or on the left of another doesn't make it a different order.

Comment: @AnarRzayev About the second comment, what I mean with wedge-shaped poset is one with two minimal elements and another above both of them. Since $a$ is necessarily a minimal element, there are two choices: one in which $b$ is the other minimal element and $c$ is above both; and another in which $b$ and $c$ swap positions relative to the previous situation.